# External smtp authentication for certain domain on zimbra

Tags: email, smtp, zimbra

I set up a local zimbra 8.7 installation on centos 7 for a local domain (domain.local). Everything in that part are working fine. But I have an external domain (outdomain.com) that is setup on cpanel. I would like to manage emails of this domain (send and receive) through local zimbra installation.

What I have done till now... I created a domain on zimbra outdomain.com and a user as the account on cpanel with the same password. On preferences tab of the zimbra account I fetch the emails from cpanel account.

The problem I have is with smtp. How can I configure this account to use cpanel smtp authentication?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with static IP address 587 port and global smtp relay setting.